# Is it possible to define AWS IAM Permissions to create only RDS Insances with specific tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I am trying to define an IAM Role + Polices to be used to deploy and manage RDS Instances via Cloudformation. So I am writing a IAM Role, that will be passed to Cloudformation for the deployment.

The Role should allow to deploy and manage RDS instances with specific tags, and not create any instance that does not have the tags.

So what I am trying int the role is this (IAM Policy):

```
    {
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "rds:req-tag/Project": "myproject" 
            }
        },
        "Action": [
            "rds:Create*",
            "rds:Restore*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
```

Yet, when I try to create RDS Instance with the Tag Project=myproject using Cloudformation, I get:

```
API: rds:CreateDBInstance User: <me> is not authorized to perform: rds:CreateDBInstance on resource: arn:aws:rds:eu-central-1:078433912766:db:ss9wm5ynvx3n8i because no identity-based policy allows the rds:CreateDBInstance action
```

Lookling through CloudTrail it seems to me, that Cloudformation does not send the tags when creating the Instance, which is probably the reason why this fails.

So I wonder: is what I am tyring even possible? Or do I have to accept the fact, that I cannot restrict Cloudformation so that it can only create RDS Instances with specific tags?

Comment: Do you have permissions to create an RDS instance?

Comment: rds:Create* should give me the permissions, should it not?

Comment: The policy you showed in the question is that being used for the role in the CloudFormation template, right? What I am asking is, does the user you are deploying the template with have permissions to create an RDS instance?

Comment: IAM does appear to support the policy condition [rds:req-tag/${TagKey}](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html) on CreateDBInstance.

Comment: The policy I am showing is attached to a role which I am passing to cloudformation for the deployment (I will edit the question to make that clearer). The user itself does not have permission to Create the RDS Instance, it only has the permission to create the cloudformation stack and pass the role.

Comment: @jarmod It does not? I can see `rds:req-tag/${TagKey}` in the Row for CreateDBInstance

Comment: I'm confirming that it *does* claim to support conditions on tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the following policy

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "rds:req-tag/Project": "myproject"
                }
            },
            "Action": [
                "rds:Create*",
                "rds:Restore*",
                "rds:AddTagsToResource"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

with the following CLI command

```bash
aws rds create-db-instance \
    --db-instance-identifier test-mysql-instance \
    --db-instance-class db.t3.micro \
    --engine mysql \
    --master-username admin \
    --master-user-password secret99 \
    --allocated-storage 20 \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --tags Key=Project,Value=myproject
```

and I can confirm that it's working as intended.

Comment: Ah, ok. Haven't tried that. Thank you! So it is probably the way cloudformation is creating the database ....